# C# Select List Containing Element Equaling Value

Tags: c#, list

I have a [QuickType JSON repository](https://app.quicktype.io/) where I save data that I grab from an API. I've figured out how to loop through the list showing elements from each "entry", however I have a hard time figuring out how to select a specific entry that contains a specific value for a property.

Example: I have a list

```
public List<Robot> Robots
```

The class Robot is as following (showing only a few properties):

```
public partial class Robot
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("activity_text")]
    public string ActivityText { get; set; }
}
```

The API contains data for two Robots. After I receive the data from the API, I would have two different lists, and both of these lists have their own values for each property.

My question is, how would I select a list depending on, for example, which ID the list contains? If the JsonProperty ID equals `1` I select the specific list which contains the ID I was looking for, since I would need the values for that specific Robot's ID.

I've used this code previously to loop through the lists and output the information in each one:

```
foreach (var robots in result.Result.Robots)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Robot ID: " + robots.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Activity: " + robots.ActivityText);
}
```

How would I go about this? I feel like my brain is fried from all of the Googling.

Comment: I dont know if im understanding you correctly, but if you want to check if a list contains a value, have a look into `.Contain()` function

Comment: Use LINQ like so `var robot = result.Result.Robots.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);`

Comment: Ideally, you get it down to **one list** that contains _both robots_, where each API call result inserts into the same list, or if the API is already returning single-item lists you take the object out as you receive it and put it in the common list.

Comment: @JamesS Well yes, that would be the first part of the problem. But if I would like to know the activity text of the the ID of robot with ID: 1 for example. How would I go about this? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @PaulSinnema What does that do exactly?

Comment: @JamesS I tried looking into .Contains() and instead found that the .Find() function might be of better use here, albeit I still do not understand how I would "choose" to select a value from the list that is found. However, when I try to output the result of  result.Result.Robots.Find(x => x.Id.Contains("PR@15"))); the output is "QuickType.Robots", which is not at all what I was expecting. I know that the list contains items because when I do a foreach on it I can output every item on every instance List<Robots>. I'm so confused.

Comment: @lemonslayer: It itterates your Robots list and checks each item for its ID. The first item found with your ID is returned or null if not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expands on what Paul commented, but as you said you don't know what that code does.

I will try to show you with code and comments:

```
// Get the first robot where Id equals to "1", if it exists
var matchingRobot = result.Result.Robots.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == "1");
// Check if the matchingRobot exists
if(matchingRobot != null){
    // Now we know it exists, we can access the property ActivityText
    Console.WriteLine("Robot with Id 1 has activity text: " + matchingRobot.ActivityText);
}
else{
    // The robot does not exist
    Console.WriteLine("There is no robot with Id 1");
}
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch! I think this is just what I needed. I'll take a look at the documentation to make sure I understand it correctly. Kudos my friend and thank you for taking the time to explain what it does!